# Understand edebug stack tracing

Tags: ivy, counsel, edebug

so for some unknown reason, whenever I edebug-defun  to  counsel-jq, I get the following error

```
edebug-syntax-error: Invalid read syntax: "Expected one of", symbolp, lambda-expr
```

stack trace is as followed

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax "Expected one of" symbolp lambda-expr)
  signal(invalid-read-syntax ("Expected one of" symbolp lambda-expr))
  edebug-syntax-error("Expected one of" symbolp lambda-expr)
  apply(edebug-syntax-error ("Expected one of" symbolp lambda-expr))
  edebug-no-match((((1 ("s" (lambda (_) (display-buffer counsel-jq-buffer)) "show"))) (1974 (1975 . 1976) (2000 (2001 . 2004) (2005 (2006 . 2012) (2013 (2014 . 2015) . 2016) (2047 (2048 . 2062) (2063 . 2080) . 2081) . 2082) (2107 . 2113) . 2114) . 2115) . 2115) "Expected one of" symbolp lambda-expr)
  apply(edebug-no-match (((1 ("s" (lambda (_) (display-buffer counsel-jq-buffer)) "show"))) (1974 (1975 . 1976) (2000 (2001 . 2004) (2005 (2006 . 2012) (2013 (2014 . 2015) . 2016) (2047 (2048 . 2062) (2063 . 2080) . 2081) . 2082) (2107 . 2113) . 2114) . 2115) . 2115) "Expected one of" (symbolp lambda-expr))
[...]
```

I have no clue how to navigate edebug stack trace. I don't even know what cause the error. I am trying to understand how ivy is implemented because I want to modify behavior of counsel-jq, so I have been edebug-defun counsel-jq alot. but few hours ago, I just got this error.

To be sure, I reverted my doom configuration to the version that I know works then reload counsel-jq package. Error still persist.

I never really understand how to navigate stacktrace, but in this case. I really have to.

any idea?

Comment: Steps I can think of: uninstall counsel-jq, quit, restart Emacs, re-install counsel-jq. Not guaranteed to work, but shows you can reproduce it reliably with your config. Next: quit, start Emacs with `emacs -Q`, then load counsel-jq and see if the problem recurs.

Comment: I should have done this too. Thank you.